# C - Thread exit sets variable to 0

Tags: c, pointers, gdb, pthreads

The following main, I would expect for found to be equal to false, which it is. However, the final print in main of `treeInfo->elem` is not `6` but `0`. I don't understand how this is possible. At no point is the variable set to 0. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
int main() {
pthread_mutex_init(&myMutex, NULL);
pthread_t threads[5];
nodeinfo_t * treeInfo = malloc(sizeof(nodeinfo_t));

int myInt = 5;
int myIntTwo = 6;
int found;
treeInfo->elem = &myIntTwo;
node_t * myTree = createTree(&myInt);
treeInfo->node = myTree;

pthread_create(&threads[3],NULL,search,treeInfo);
pthread_join(threads[3],(void *) &found);

printf("THE VALUE OF ELEM IS %d", *(treeInfo->elem));
}
```

```
int search(void * args) {
    nodeinfo_t * nodeInfo = (nodeinfo_t *) args;
    node_t * node = nodeInfo->node;
    int * toFind = nodeInfo->elem;
    
    if (node == NULL) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (node->parent == NULL) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
    }

    if (node->elem == *toFind) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
        return 1;
    } else if (node->elem< *toFind) {
        nodeInfo->node = node->right;
        return search(nodeInfo);
    } else if (node->elem > *toFind) {
        nodeInfo->node = node->left;
        return search(nodeInfo);
    }
}
```

Edit: Made reproducible

```
typedef struct _node {
    int elem;
    struct _node * parent;
    struct _node * left;
    struct _node * right;
} node_t;

typedef struct _nodeinfo {
    node_t * node;
    int * elem;
} nodeinfo_t;

pthread_mutex_t myMutex;

node_t * createTree(int * firstElem) {
    // allocate memory in heap for size of node type
    node_t * root = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    // set element of root to first int in tree
    root->elem = *firstElem;
    // set everything else blank
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
    root->parent = NULL;
    // return pointer to start of tree node
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Especially, what does the `createTree` function do?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but because of the assignment `nodeInfo->node = node->right;` (and the other one as well) you will *loose* nodes from your "tree" and have *memory leaks*.

Comment: The lessons for today: Always read manual pages, references and examples. And always build with extra warnings enabled, that you treat as errors that *must* be fixed.

Comment: Why did you delete all the code in your question, thereby invalidating the answer? I have reverted the edit.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you think the thread functions returns `int` values. They do in fact return *pointers* (more specifically `void *`).

If you build with warnings enabled you should be getting a warning that the `search` function doesn't match what `pthread_create` expects.

The `pthread_join` function expects a pointer *to a pointer* of type `void **`.

This mismatch in return types will lead to *undefined behavior*.

---

To solve your problem you need to return a pointer from the `search` function. However, this is one of the cases where it's commonly considered okay to cast values as pointers, with a special cast.

For example:

```
void *search(void * args) {
    nodeinfo_t * nodeInfo = (nodeinfo_t *) args;
    node_t * node = nodeInfo->node;
    int * toFind = nodeInfo->elem;
    
    if (node == NULL) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
        return (void *) (intptr_t) 0;  // Note the double casting here
    }

    // ...
}
```

You then need to use a pointer to get the returned value, and do the opposite cast to get the value:

```
void *found_ptr;
pthread_join(threads[3], &found_ptr);
int found = (int) (intptr_t) found_ptr;
```

---

As for what *probably* happens is that you're on a 64-bit system, where pointers are 64 bits but `int` are only 32 bits. This mismatch in sizes will lead to a stack-smashing bug where the variable `myIntTwo` is overwritten by the thread s returned value.